# Xamarin Forms for Android, how to share and open a file?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm new to Xamarin and trying to figure it out. There are two points in which I can’t understand.
First, I'm trying to share a file:

```
byte[] fileArray = ....
var sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
sharingIntent.SetType("application/octet-stream");
sharingIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, fileArray);
StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(sharingIntent, "Send file"));
```

I get an error: Error loading. The request contains no data.

Second, I figured out how to open a file and can get the path to it:
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent intent)

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    switch (resultCode)
    {
        case Result.Ok:
            string path = intent.Data.Path;
         break;
    }
}
```

The path to the file in the Downloads folder /document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/MyFile.dat
File Path in SdCard /document/1513-1812:MyFile.dat

How can I open these files?
Or how can I get them as Byte []?

I will be happy for any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> The path to the file in the Downloads folder /document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/MyFile.dat File Path in SdCard /document/1513-1812:MyFile.dat.How can I open these files? Or how can I get them as Byte []?

If you want to open file from Download folder in Xamarin.Forms, you can use DependencyService to do this.

Firstly, create class in PCL.

```
public interface IFileSystem
{

    byte[] ReadAllByteS();

}
```

Then implement in android:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(FileSystemImplementation))]
namespace demo3.Droid
{
public class FileSystemImplementation : IFileSystem
{

    public byte[] ReadAllByteS()
    {
        if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(MainActivity.mactivity, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted)
        {
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(MainActivity.mactivity, new String[] { Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage }, 1);

            return null;
        }
        var filePath = Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
        var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath.AbsolutePath, "testfile/hello.txt");
        return File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    }
}
```

}

Finally, you can get byte[] by the following code:

```
 private void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        byte[] dataBuffer = DependencyService.Get<IFileSystem>().ReadAllByteS();

    }
```

**Update:**

If you want to choose one file and get this file path to open, I suggest you can use **Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker** to choose file and get file path.

Firstly, installing **Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker** by nuget package...

Then modifying IFileSystem class in PCL :

```
public interface IFileSystem
{

    byte[] ReadAllByteS(string path);

}
```

and FileSystemImplementation class in Android:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(FileSystemImplementation))]
namespace demo3.Droid
{
public class FileSystemImplementation : IFileSystem
{

    public byte[] ReadAllByteS(string path)
    {
        if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(MainActivity.mactivity, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted)
        {
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(MainActivity.mactivity, new String[] { Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage }, 1);

            return null;
        }
        //var filePath = Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
        //var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath.AbsolutePath, "testfile/hello.txt");
        return File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    }
}
```

}

Finally, you can get byte[]:

```
 private async void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileData file = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();

        if (file != null)
        {

            string path = file.FilePath;
            byte[] dataBuffer = DependencyService.Get<IFileSystem>().ReadAllByteS(path);             
        }


    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Everything is clear with this: var filePath = Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryDownloads);

But what about an arbitrary path, for example, opening a file with an SDcard?

Comment: @Neff If you want to choose one file and get this file path to open, please see my update.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker, I just wanted to understand how to achieve this without plugins. In addition, Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker does not always work correctly on real devices, for example, it cannot open a file from the download folder on a real device.

Comment: @Neff I use  Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker to open a file from the download folder successfully. If you don't use Plugin to choose, you may create file picker in Android:https://github.com/xamarin/docs-archive/tree/master/Recipes/android/data/files/browse_files

Comment: Thank you for participating. I think I'm trying to make my FilePicker, it will be a good experience.

Comment: @Neff If you have solution, please share your solution here, it may be helpful to others, thanks.